# WebForms: DataBind to Text Property of derived CheckBox control

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a page which has a CheckBox control as such:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="Save" runat="server" Text='<%= SomePageMethod("param") %>' />
```

This works just fine, the SomePageMethod is called and the page renders the correct text next to the check box.

Now, we are doing some work on testing WebForms pages, and as part of this work, we build a trivial derived class so we can inject an interface:

```
namespace MyControls
{
    public interface ICheckBox
    {
        bool Visible { get; set; }
    }

    public class CheckBox : ICheckBox, System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox
    {
    }
}
```

I then import the class onto my page thus:

```
<%@ Register Namespace="MyControls" Assembly="MyControls" TagPrefix="vm" %>
```

And change the control definition to:

```
<vm:CheckBox ID="Save" runat="server" Text='<%= SomePageMethod("param") %>' />
```

Now, the data binding expression is never called and so my check box has no text.

Any ideas why this wouldn't work? Nearly everything else we have done with these controls is working perfectly, but this one has me stumped.

Note: Edited to remove the ambiguity of having the `Checked` property in the made-up interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be as simple as calling data bind on the page?
I created a small test that mirrors your requirements,
and the text wasn't bound until I explicitly called `DataBind()`
on the page or individually on each control.

Below is an example of an ASP CheckBox and a custom CheckBox which
implements `ICheckBox`

**TestPage.aspx**

```
...
<vm:CheckBox ID="VmCheckBox" runat="server" Text="<%# GetCheckBoxText(23)%>"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="AspCheckBox" runat="server" Text="<%# GetCheckBoxText(23)%>" />
```

***NOTE*** that I used `#` instead of `=` in the binder, i.e., `<%# ... %>`

**TestPage.aspx.cs**

```
...
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind() // Binds all objects on page
    
    // ...Or individually bind controls
    VmCheckBox.DataBind()
    AspCheckBox.DataBind()
}
```

Comment: You misunderstand. If I just replace the asp control in my page with the vm version, everything works and everything compiles. By inheriting from the WebForms.CheckBox, the vm class implements the Checked method. What is not happening is the data binding of the Text property.

Comment: I did misunderstand, check the edits I made was that the problem?

Comment: This is exactly the issue. It turns out, deep in the bowels of our app, we have code that loops through all the controls on a page and calls DataBind() on them. But it has a whitelist because certain controls don't like to be explicitly data bound. Adding my derived control to the whitelist solves the issue.